# jQuery $.ajax succeed but serv doesn't receive any data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, load

I work on a pagination system that wouldn't reload the whole page but just refresh the contents.
I retrieve the requested page with the value contained in a ID and want to send it to the server for the process.

The `success` is reached but my php script does not recognize the `$_POST['page']` value.
Here is the JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#containerWrapper').on('click', '.holder a', function (event) {

        var page = $(this).attr('id');
        var url = "cart.php";
        event.preventDefault();

        // Launch of the Ajax query to refresh the current page
        $.ajax({
            url: "cart.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {page: page},
            success: function()
            {
                alert('Success, delivered page: ' + page);
                $('#containerWrapper').load(url + " #containerWrapper");
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Here the PHP, which i think isn't the real problem:

```
if (isset($_POST['page']) && ($_POST['page'])>0 && ($_POST['page'])<= $nbPages)
    {
        $cPage = htmlspecialchars($_POST['page']);
    }
```

I've ready many topics but haven't found any relative problem for the now.

Comment: FYI `$_POST['page']` is a string

Comment: Have you watched the request / response of the AJAX call in the browser's console? Your success function does not return anything. the `load()` function is a different AJAX shortcut method in jQuery and if you're using that you really don't need the rest of the AJAX that you've written.

Comment: @Musa it doesn't matter, assuming you're talking about the comparison operators.

Comment: Yes Jay, a console.log() I did some revisions ago revealed that the Ajax transfert succeeded (success was reached as I said). But I didn't realized load() was an Ajax's shortcut method, thanks for the tip again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have too much code, it is not necessary for your purposes to bury a `load()` statement in an AJAX call. You could simply do this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#containerWrapper').on('click', '.holder a', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = "cart.php";
        var page = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#containerWrapper').load(url + " #containerWrapper", {page: page});
    }); 
});
```

[`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) does allow you to send data to the requested page via a second arguement.

Comment: Indeed I've make something way too complicated, thanks for the tip, didn't know we can join data with load() like that :)